# Adding third party js script on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a script of a chat component developed by third parties, which has an option to include it in a website incorporating the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Comm100API=Comm100API||{};(function(t){function e(e){var a=document.createElement("script"),c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=e+t.site_id,c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c)}t.chat_buttons=t.chat_buttons||[],t.chat_buttons.push({code_plan:147,div_id:"comm100-button-147"}),t.site_id=228642,t.main_code_plan=147,e("https://chatserver.comm100.com/livechat.ashx?siteId="),setTimeout(function(){t.loaded||e("https://hostedmax.comm100.com/chatserver/livechat.ashx?siteId=")},5e3)})(Comm100API||{})
</script>
```

In this way a clickable popup is incorporated, which when pressed opens the chat window.

The idea is to add it in a reactive application that already
is built, within a component of it.

If we add the code in the index.html of the application, the popup is nested in the body of the application, occupying a fixed position on the screen.

We need insert chat view on this component, and don't know how can do it:

```
interface Props {
  showVideoChat: false,
}

class VideoChatActionsPane extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {

    if (this.props.showVideoChat) {
      return (
          <div className="wdrgy-videoChat-menu">
            <div className="wdrgy-wc-header-videochat">
              <div className="wdrgy-brand">
                <span className="wdrgy-title">Title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              { // Chat component should be inserted here
              }
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: honestly I would just add the script to the componentDidMount. you can see examples which added the facebook scripts...but the idea would be to append that script to where ever the heck you want. and it will be triggered by whatever you want. you can use script tags or just a self contained function and create the tags with js...

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:

You can use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to add the script to the head section of your document, like this:

```
<Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Comm100API = Comm100API || {};
        (function(t) {
        ...
        })(Comm100API || {})
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

And then just add the div with react:

```
<div id="comm100-button-xxxx"></div>
```